# Mongodb Collection Transformation

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have a below collection looks like a normal Rdbms table so to gain advantages of Json and mongodb i would like to transform from one to another form

i am new to MongoDB.

```
[{
        "ccp": 1,
        "period": 1,
        "sales": 100,
        "units": 50
    },
    {
        "ccp": 1,
        "period": 2,
        "sales": 200,
        "units": 50
    },
    {
        "ccp": 2,
        "period": 1,
        "sales": 100,
        "units": 50
    },
    {
        "ccp": 2,
        "period": 2,
        "sales": 200,
        "units": 50
    }
]
```

I am looking to convert above collection to below format

```
[{
    "ccp": 1,
    "periods": [{
            "period": 1,
            "sales": 100,
            "units": 50
        },
        {
            "period": 2,
            "sales": 200,
            "units": 50
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ccp": 2,
    "periods": [{
            "period": 1,
            "sales": 100,
            "units": 50
        },
        {
            "period": 2,
            "sales": 200,
            "units": 50
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: Read up on [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

Comment: is it ok to convert data with javascript?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya , i am looking for mongo query

Comment: can i know what you want to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be not the efficient one, but this is how you can achieve this using aggregation framework of mongodb

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$group : {_id : "$ccp",
    periods : {$push : {period : "$period", sales : "$sales", units : "$units" }}}},
   {$project : { periods : 1, "ccp" : "$_id" , _id : 0 }}
  ])
```